# Error creating a phonegap android project cscript is not a recognised internal or external command

Tags: android, cordova, windows-7

am getting started with android using phone gap but command prompt returns the following error when i run `create C:\phonegap-2.3.0\phonegap-2.3.0\lib\android\bin>create        C:\Users\paul\Documents\Webnux\AndroidProjects com.Webnuxs.Flames Flames
   'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.`
any solutions out there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.no/2012/11/getting-create-command-to-work-on.html): Make sure you have Windows Scripting Host installed. If you do then you need to make sure that the path to cscript.exe is in your PATH environment variable.

Just in case, [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110529123006AABGsYv) is how to enabled it on Win 7.